# Converting clob to xml parse error

Tags: xml, plsql, clob

I'm trying to convert clob to xml. I'm getting the following errors:

[image]

ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token in: '/KrediBilgi/'

Procedure:

```
procedure parse_xml(response in CLOB) is
    l_xmlType XMLTYPE;
  begin
   l_xmlType := XMLTYPE.CreateXML(response); 
   FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/Durum/text()') as durum
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/GuncelRisk/text()') as risk
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/GuncelRiskTarih/text()') as tarih
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/KrediHesapNo/text()') as hesapNo
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/KrediKod/text()') as krediKod
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/KrediKonu/text()') as krediKonu
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/KrediTur/text()') as krediTur
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/KrediTutar/text()') as krediTutar
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/PbKod/text()') as pbKod
      ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/KrediBilgi/ProjeKod/text()') as projeKod
FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(l_xmlType,'/KrediBilgi/'))) p
) LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(r.durum);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.risk);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.tarih);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.hesapNo);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.krediKod);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.krediKonu);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.krediTur);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.krediTutar);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.pbKod);
  dbms_output.put_line(r.projeKod);
  END LOOP;
 end parse_xml;
```

Comment: Can you post you `response` as well which you are passing to the proc.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml structure:

```
<KrediBilgi>
    <Durum>text1</Durum>
    <GuncelRisk>text2</GuncelRisk>
    ...
</KrediBilgi>
```

try to remove slash '/' from this line:

```
FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(l_xmlType,'KrediBilgi'))) p
```

and you can also remove first slash from lines like this

```
'KrediBilgi/Durum/text()'
```